# Hide Featured Image box - isn't working?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

Currently I have this code in my function file:

```
    // REMOVE POST META BOXES
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
    if ( ! current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-post_tag', 'post', 'advanced' );
        remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', 'post', 'advanced' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

And the tags meta box has been disabled, but not the featured image box. I've looked elsewhere in my functions to see if anything is making it appear again but I cannot seem to find anything.

Is there perhaps something I am missing elsewhere?

Comment: See [Remove the Featured Image Meta Box](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4936/remove-the-featured-image-meta-box) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context or the 3rd parameter of `remove_meta_box()` function for *tags meta box* and *featured image meta box* is `side`. And perfect hook to remove meta box is `add_meta_boxes`. So try the following code, hope it'll work as expected.

```
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-post_tag', 'post', 'side' );
        remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', 'post', 'side' );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That did the trick! I think it was the hook as I had tried 'normal' and 'side' and nothing was working. Yay!!

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked :)